# Check if database table has been updated

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a model class 'Shop' with a related database table. The table is large and we are changing the way the clients load the data.

Up until now, mobile clients would just retrieve the whole table and reload the list in app, but now developers started to work with local memory, so they would not have to reload all records every time.

So from them I expect to get a timestamp of when a user has last logged in and check if any records have been added/updated after that and return the new/updated data, but I just do not know where to start from.

Comment: This is trivial: Just find records where created > timestamp. Do you really need somebody to write that condition for you?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).